# LiveSDK XMPP android sample not working

Tags: android, xmpp, hotmail, windows-live-messenger

I try to implement [LiveSDK XMPP android sample](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/tree/master/Samples/XMPP-Samples/Android) for messenger service of Hotmail chat.

I got the authentication token, as shown in LogCat preview,

```
07-05 09:52:06.408: I/onPageFinished(21312): <!>com.ms.wlm.WLMActivity$MyWebViewClient 319<!> Page - http://www.slktechlabs.com/#access_token=EwAoAq1DBAAUlbRWyAJjK5w968Ru3Cyt%2f6GvwXwAAaoVuXcoTjxcoOkoec%2fKvwaSgtfYv1N9duMQHPFph7mdbXsfOiTf9EDe1PtFJ6YdjcHdKfbEwbh8LyVMHtj88iXIkhFBWcfDMVe4lNwfL9GKJq5CQKeeNHhPKGWe5cBOyIFnH8lBi0uPAQaJxsrUYjo800%2bgiMZyM8ammDU70gGto7TlavrpjuowtMSQqYJSMXF1Pjs4Cq6eMAPcoUrtLG1xFf2wiAF2%2f5a8kM97cVGarMGi62HUpZWrp1f4sBuaImzo8C8DMy7LafE42IUHPHalne54oHMNDLB3mXh9pvXTdrP8XLSfaDkNgbuMIDP3yEdBuPQuwnl%2fMfuca9hXbE8DZgAACCRBkUfjJ6s7%2bABg%2bAUJRL%2ftxNgDkG%2fquQ0D1q6kozu24jPVF9DxISPK6BDRyDpkO0uFvUaC4eskE93t8obfYdKSdNl3jGyoyiSG1%2fw3Mrisa%2bChMiEuLVzS1tP%2fAKEchYqdEvyn%2bn%2bYaybyCArNYMgQEKIg3PFoLOAh6QImPo21tMbu9KIBYOyDb0B88y9WNErxMJb%2bACRy4iskUrlaxniOXi92RX6fH40cmkC0Bfy%2b6T4CmZ6NTLXJoGqF6nd8l3RVJBEUz%2fLL%2baFGpcol3RZja0vyZeUTQkwwJiTm0wcX9VpnkMAO10cyony5QghkmC8c8Ts9tDvVpDZseGtwmHUtnwAA&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=wl.messenger&authentication_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsICJraWQiOiIwIiwgInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ2ZXIiOjEsICJpc3MiOiJ1cm46d2luZG93czpsaXZlaWQiLCAiZXhwIjoxMzQxNTQ4NTE3LCAiYXVkIjoid3d3LnNsa3RlY2hsYWJzLmNvbSIsICJ1aWQiOi
I2N2Q2NDcxNTRmOTEyYWQ1MWU2OTI1YWFmZGIwNGM0OSIsICJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OmFwcHVyaSI6IiIsICJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OmFwcGlkIjoiMDAwMDAwMDA0MDBDQjk4RSJ9.NGQB8_NBT8twZOmJvsrrUUjQkX2gQeRCIY5sMwvObjM
```

But when that code run `this.connection.connect();` in `XmppClient.java` file after getting authentication token, it throws `<see-other-host>` error.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sample does not work anymore after the latest server update in April. See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826554.aspx

you have to read the hostname given in the  error and reconnect to this host. This seems to be their way of load balancing ;-)

Comment: How can we get `see-other-host` xml stream as response? we only get `W/System.err(30993): stream:error (see-other-host)` error in logcat.

Comment: I am not that familiar with smack, but I think I would modify ReconnectionManager.java and StreamError.java to reconnect to the given host